# Why does decreasing the font size of a button not affect the parent divs height?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, button, font-size

Seems like a simple issue, but can't figure out the answer. My code is in the link below. when the font size of the button is set - it decreases the font size as intended, but the parent div does not shrink to the height of the button. So there is this gap between the border of the parent div and its button child. Why is this happening, and what can be done to fix it?

I have tried decreasing the margin and padding of the button, thinking that there was some default styles applied, but none of it worked.

https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-breeze-gztjxd?file=/src/App.js

```
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <>
          <div style={{ border: "10px solid green", padding: "10px" }}>
            <div style={{ border: "1px solid red", display: 'flex' }}>
              <button style={{ border: "1px solid green", padding: "0px" }}>
                <div style={{ "font-size": "5px" }}>My Text</div>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
```

Even simplified the problem still persists. In this example I would expect the parent div(s) height to collapse to fit the button.

EDIT: I found that adding a flex property to the container of the button fixes it, but i don't know why this is.

```html
<div style="border:10px solid green; padding:10px">
<div style="border:1px solid red;">
<button style="border:1px solid green;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:5px;">My Text</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put code IN the question so that if the linked item goes away your question still has value

Comment: Be aware that the `button` element can only contain [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content). Having a `div` in there is invalid.

Comment: You're not decreasing the font size of the button, you're decreasing the font size of it's child.

Comment: I've took the liberty of editing your question to include a snippet illustrating the problem.

Comment: The container has a line-height, which sets the minimum height it can shrink to if it contains inline content such as a button.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the div: "display: inline" or "display:inline-block" to its shrink to the content.

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ border: "10px solid green", padding: "10px" }}>
        <div style={{ border: "1px solid red", display: 'inline-block' }}>
          <button style={{ border: "1px solid green", padding: "0px" }}>
            <div style={{ "font-size": "5px" }}>My Text</div>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```